# How to format ISO date in React-Native

Tags: javascript, date, react-native

I am getting date data in this format from my API:

```
"2018-12-26T05:00:29"
```

however I need to display this in the application front end in a different format like this:

```
"Monday, Nov 26 at 10:00 am"
```

How can I achieve this in react-native?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using a third-party library like [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) for advanced date parsing and formatting. Using moment, you can [format the date string](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) as required via the following pattern:

```
// dddd for full week day, MMM for abreviated month, DD for date, etc
moment(inputDate).format("dddd, MMM DD at HH:mm a")
```

The momentjs library works well with react-native and can be easily installed by:

```
npm install moment --save
```

and imported into your project:

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

Here's a snippet demonstrating the pattern shown above:

```js
var inputDate = "2018-12-26T05:00:29";

var outputDate = moment(inputDate).format("dddd, MMM DD at HH:mm a");

console.log(outputDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

While [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) can resolve this issue quickly, it's however a pretty big library to use for a single use case. I recommend using [`date-fns` instead](https://date-fns.org/). It's lite.

I come out of this thanks to https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/376#issuecomment-353871093.

Despite the solution, I did some perfection on Date Field Symbol. You may need to use `dd` instead of `DD` / `yyyy` instead of `YYYY` for formatting days of the month / for formatting years.

Read the doc here: https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/master/docs/unicodeTokens.md